# Группировка по значению в многомерном массиве и сумма сгруппированных ключей

Tags: php, массивы

Есть класс php

```
stdClass Object(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 4332
        [user_id] => 3
        [useru_id] => 2
        [date] => 1474045582
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 4333
        [user_id] => 3
        [useru_id] => 2
        [date] => 1474045583
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 4334
        [user_id] => 4
        [useru_id] => 2
        [date] => 1474045591
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 4336
        [user_id] => 3
        [useru_id] => 2
        [date] => 1474045594
    )
)
```

Нужно сгруппировать его по useru_id (он одинаковый у всех =2) и чтобы на выходе было известно количество сгруппированных ключей (для user_id = 3 получается в сумме 3, для user_id = 4 получается в сумме 1).

Должно получиться вот так

```
stdClass Object ( 
    [3] => stdClass Object 
    ( 
        [id] => 4336 
        [user_id] => 3 
        [useru_id] => 2 
        [date] => 1474045594 
        [count] => 3 
    ) 
    [4] => stdClass Object 
    ( 
        [id] => 4334 
        [user_id] => 4 
        [useru_id] => 2 
        [date] => 1474045591 
        [count] => 1 
    ) 
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$summary = array();
$counter = array();
foreach($array as $row){
    if(isset($counter[$row['user_id']])) $counter[$row['user_id']]++;
    else $counter[$row['user_id']] = 1;
    $summary[$row['user_id']][] = $row;
}
```

В `$summary` группировка, в `$counter` размер каждой группы.

Comment: Спасибо, так работает, но нужно, чтобы получился 1 массив (у Вас 2 $summary и $counter). Не знаю как вставить код, но нужно чтобы получилось так: stdClass Object
(
    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4336
            [user_id] => 3
            [useru_id] => 2
            [date] => 1474045594
   [count] => 3
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4334
            [user_id] => 4
            [useru_id] => 2
            [date] => 1474045591
   [count] => 1
        )
)

Comment: @skillful я отредактировал ваш вопрос. Каким образом тогда должны выбираться все остальные поля? `id`, `useru_id` и `date`?